# convert date format DD-MM-YYYY TO DD MMM YYYY format

Tags: javascript

Is their any inbuilt method to display date as DD MMM YYYY (08 Jan 2018) format in javascript
Currently I am using the below code for  date format.

```
$('#timeTable th:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
                if($(this).attr('Id') === 'totalHours') return;
                $(this).text(dateObj.getDate()+'/'+dateObj.getMonth()+'/'+dateObj.getFullYear());
                dateObj.setDate(dateObj.getDate() + 1);
                });
```

Comment: use date.js or other date libraries to format the date as you want

Answer (score 0):

Nothing built in. Your approach is pretty much as good as you'll get without a library.

Note that months are zero indexed, so you need to add one to the result of `getMonth`.

*EDIT*

If your program doesn't need to run after the year 9999 you might get away with:

```
dateObj.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

`toISOString` produces a value like `2018-01-08T08:52:17.406Z`. You can just use the first 10 characters.